# How do I set time limits for users on mikrotik hotspot?

Tags: mikrotik-routeros

I want users to be logged in for a certain amount of time and logged out when they reach the time limit but I also want the user to be able login again if they wish to just by logging in again since users will be sharing the usernames provided to them.

I don't want to use the trial feature because I want users to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the hotspot user profile near to the users tab in it select the profile if you haven't created a profile then it will be under the default set the logout time for the user. It is also used to limit the speed for the users who're all in that profile. I think this what you have been searching for if it help full comment it below.

Comment: I found everything I needed in user profiles section. Thanks.